# Passing a Double Variable into a SQL Query using VBA Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```vb
Dim dbCurr as DAO.Database
Dim rsCnf as DAO.Recordset
Dim cnfId as String

cnfId = "SELECT [Cnf].[CNF ID#], [Cnf].[Title] FROM [Cnf] WHERE ([Cnf].[CNF ID#]= ' & Me.txtCNF & ' )"
set rsCNF = dbCurr.OpenRecordset(cnfId)
```

I get a data mismatch error.  I know it has something to do with the variable since if I just put in a number like 1331.1 the query runs smoothly.

Comment: `Me.txtCNF` must be concatenated to the string, not be part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quotes around numeric values. So try:

```vb
Dim dbCurr As DAO.Database
Dim rsCnf  As DAO.Recordset
Dim cnfId  As String

cnfId = "SELECT [Cnf].[CNF ID#], [Cnf].[Title] FROM [Cnf] WHERE ([Cnf].[CNF ID#] = " & Str(Me.txtCNF) & ")"

Set dbCurr = CurrentDb
Set rsCNF = dbCurr.OpenRecordset(cnfId)
```